# Glossaries PDF bookmark contains equals sign before

Tags: pdf, koma-script, glossaries, bookmarks

I am writting a thesis with the scrreprt document class and the glossaries package. I have a problem with the PDF bookmarks of the glossaries. As you can see in the picture below there is a equal sign in front of the glossary bookmarks. I do not know why the equal sign appears in front of the bookmarks and i want to get rid of it. I am very grateful for your help.

[image: Equal sign before the bookmark]

Here is a minimal working document that you could use for testing:

```
%##### Praeambel: ##########################################################################

\documentclass[
    12pt,                                       
    DIV=13,                                     
    paper=A4,                               
    parskip=half,
    listof=totoc                                
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Hyperlinks:
\usepackage[                                    
    bookmarks         = true,                   
    bookmarksnumbered = true,                   
    pdfpagemode       = {UseOutlines},      
    plainpages        = false,              
    pdfpagelabels     = true,                   
    colorlinks        = true,               
    linkcolor         = {black},            
    citecolor         = {black},                
    urlcolor          = {black},                
]{hyperref}

% Glossaries:
\usepackage[
    acronym,
    toc,
]{glossaries}

\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}{
    name=formula,
    description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{afk}{AFK}{Away from keyboard}
\newacronym{btw}{BTW}{By the way}
\newacronym{fyi}{FYI}{For your interest}
\newacronym{asap}{ASAP}{As soon as possible}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                     
\usepackage{blindtext}                      


%##### Text: ##############################################################################
\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents    
    
    \printglossary[title={\protect\centering\acronymname}, type=\acronymtype, style=long3col-booktabs]
    \printglossary[title={\protect\centering\glossaryname}, style=long3col-booktabs]

    \clearpage

    \chapter{Einleitung}
    The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable for documents that include 
    \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.
    \acrfull{fyi} das Akronym \acrshort{asap}, steht für \acrlong{asap}. \acrshort{btw} ich bin jetzt 
    \acrshort{afk}.

    \section{Motivation}
    \blindtext
    
    \listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\printglossary[title={\texorpdfstring{\protect\centering\acronymname}{\acronymname}},...` for the titles.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer thank you very much for this solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ulrike Fischer provided the following working solution:

Change

```
\printglossary[
    title={\protect\centering\acronymname}, 
    type=\acronymtype, 
    style=long3col-booktabs
]
```

to

```
\printglossary[
    title={\texorpdfstring{\protect\centering\acronymname}{\acronymname}},
    type=\acronymtype, 
    style=long3col-booktabs
]
```